# Form validation JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My form validation function is not working properly. The error msg displayed in the `innerHTML` element goes away as soon as it appears, like the page is being `refreshed`.I am new in `javascript`. I don't know whet seems to be the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(form) {
        var user = form.txtUsername;
        var institute = form.txtinstitute;
        var email = form.txtemail;
        var pass1 = form.pwdpassword1;
        var pass2 = form.pwdpassword2;
        var check = "";

        check = validateFilled(pass2);
        check = validateFilled(pass1);
        check = validateFilled(email);
        if (check == true) {
            check = validateEmail(email);
        }
        check = validateFilled(institute);
        check = validateFilled(user);
        if (checked == false) {
            return false;
        }
        //return true;
    }

    function validateFilled(control) {
        if (control.value.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById(control.id).nextSibling.innerHTML = "* required";
            document.getElementById(control.id).focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function validateEmail(control) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]        {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (!(re.test(email.value))) {
            document.getElementById(email.id).nextSibling.innerHTML = " *invalid email";
            document.getElementById(email.id).focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: When you submit a form, the page get a post back event. To prevents your page to be reload, add in your function where you handle the click event an event.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks......I am new in javascript and in this forum, I will improve my format of asking qestions @EmilLundberg

Comment: @Jerome2606...Thanks for replying but I dont understand wat u mean

Answer (score 0):

```
    check = validateFilled(pass2);
    check = validateFilled(pass1);  //overrides check above
    check = validateFilled(email);  //overrides check above
    if (check == true) {
        check = validateEmail(email);//overrides check above
    }
    if (check == true) {
        check = validateEmail(email);//overrides check above
    }
    check = validateFilled(institute);//overrides check above
    check = validateFilled(user);//overrides check above
```

So if any of those are false, the other checks under it will make it true. Bad design....

You need to only set check to false if the validation fails....